# What/where is the "mountain of Your inheritance" in Exodus 15:17?

Tags: exodus, hebrew-bible, moses, torah

What/where is the "mountain of Your inheritance" in Exodus 15:17?

> "You will bring them in and plant them in the mountain of Your
>   inheritance..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the two commentaries below.  The Phrase "mountain of your inheritance" only occurs in Ex 15:17 but is alluded to in Ps 74:2.

The passage in Ex 15 is part of the great "Song of Moses" recording God's victory and deliverance from the hands of the pursuing Egyptians.  It not only celebrated the recent victory but what that entailed - a clear path to the promised land.  That is, the Song of Moses celebrated the past and looked forward to more of God's dealing that he would fulfil His promises to Israel in their own settled land, complete with Sanctuary to worship God.

Ellicott observes for Ex 15:17 -

> In the mountain of thine inheritance.--Some suppose Mount Moriah to be
>   especially intended; but it is better to understand Canaan generally,
>   which is a country consisting almost entirely of mountains, with only
>   two plains of any extent--those of Sharon and Esdraelon.
>
> The Sanctuary can only mean the place where God was "to put his name."
>   (See the comment on Exodus 15:13.) This is spoken of as already "made"
>   and "established," because it was so in the Divine counsels, as Moses
>   very well knew. (See Deuteronomy 12:5; Deuteronomy 12:11; Deuteronomy
>   12:14; Deuteronomy 14:23-24, &c.)

The Pulpit Commentary also observes:

> Thou shalt bring them in - i.e., give them possession of the laud. And
>   plant them - i.e., fix them firmly in it - enable them to take root
>   there. The mountain of thine inheritance. The land of Canaan, which is
>   almost wholly mountainous, and which God had given as an inheritance
>   to his people (Genesis 15:7; Hebrews 11:8). The sanctuary. See the
>   comment on verse 13. Which thy hands have established. Moses sees in
>   idea the sanctuary already set up, and God dwelling in it; and
>   emphasises his conviction by using the past tense.

Benson also reaches a similar conclusion:

> Thou shalt bring them in — If he thus bring them out of Egypt, he will
>   bring them into Canaan; for he has begun, and will he not make an end?
>   Thou wilt plant them in the place made for thee to dwell in — It is
>   good dwelling where God dwells, in his church on earth, and in his
>   church in heaven. In the mountains — The mountainous country of
>   Canaan. The sanctuary which thy hands have established — Will as
>   surely establish as if it were done already.

Comment: Let's suppose Psalms 74:2 is the strength of your argument. Even then it doesn't address the context as to how that theme develops in the Old Testament(i.e. in the place which God shall choose). If the question is asking for an ultimate answer then perhaps you've answered it, however the people singing this would not have necessarily come to that conclusion. The woman in John 4, for example, has an interesting argument with Jesus about the place of the sanctuary(our fathers worshipped in this mountain); the point being that important paradigms are often developed in the Bible.

Comment: I did some additional research after asking the question. Israel is on hilly terain. I also remembered that Israel is commonly referred to as "Mt. Zion". That could possibly be the meaning. Israel was simply singing "You will bring and plant us in your Promised Land."

Comment: @Philip - correct - that is what the above commentators are exactly saying.

Comment: Strange that the commentators have to labour an attempt at a geographical significance (of miniscule proportions)and have ignored the expressions 'Mount S/Zion', and its connection with Lebanon, Psalm 133/Hermon ; and 'Horeb' (Mount Sinai but named otherwise). +1.